# DIV по горизонтальному центру другого DIV

Tags: html, css

Есть такая простая разметка:

```css
.block {
  width: 337px;
  height: 56px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
}

.miniblock {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 51px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="miniblock"></div>
    <div class="miniblock"></div>
    <div class="miniblock"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

блоки class="miniblock" появляются динамично и из количество может быть разным. Может быть один, а может быть и 6. В ряд влезает 6 блоков.

Суть задачи, что бы блоки class="miniblock" всегда выравнивались по центру относительно блока class="block", а не прилагали к левому краю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вот так как-то**

```css
.block {
  position:relative;
  width: 337px;
  height: 56px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  text-align:center;
}
.wrap {
  
  display:inline-block;
 }
.miniblock {

  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 51px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="block">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="miniblock"></div>
    <div class="miniblock"></div>
    <div class="miniblock"></div>

           
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="miniblock"></div>
    <div class="miniblock"></div>
    <div class="miniblock"></div>
    <div class="miniblock"></div>
    <div class="miniblock"></div>
    <div class="miniblock"></div>       
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

У `.wrap` добавляем `display: table;` и `margin: 0 auto;` Как-то так:

```css
.block {
  width: 337px;
  height: 56px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
}

.wrap {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.miniblock {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 51px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="miniblock"></div>
    <div class="miniblock"></div>
    <div class="miniblock"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="block">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="miniblock"></div>
    <div class="miniblock"></div>
    <div class="miniblock"></div>
    <div class="miniblock"></div>
    <div class="miniblock"></div>
    <div class="miniblock"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Конечно, можно к `.block` добавить `text-align:center;`, а к `.wrap` добавить `display:inline-block;` и всё заработает как нужно. Свойство `display` -  определяет, как элемент должен быть показан в документе, значение `inline-block` - расположить в ряд несколько элементов с заданными размерами. Хоть `text-align` и отвечает за выравнивание текста в пределах элемента, но установив его значение в `center` - выровняем блоки по центру.

Хорошие ссылки с полезными ответами:

- [How to horizontally center a  in another ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/114543/5275890)
- [How can I center a div within another div?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15376634/5275890)

Comment: а можно просто для `.wrap` сделать `margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;` - правда не знаю на сколько это законно)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, да, вот только что наткнулся: [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/114549/5275890) прикреплю ссылку в ответ.

Comment: этот метод не подойдет если там 6 блоков т.к. сломается на моем ответе есть немного вариант иначе

Comment: @Duoxx все работает, не наговаривайте!

Comment: Я написал это до правки

Answer (score 0):

Прием основан на позиционировании элементов

```css
.block {
  position:relative;
  width: 337px;
  height: 56px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
}
.miniblock {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 51px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 1.5px;
}
.wrap {
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="miniblock"></div>
    <div class="miniblock"></div>
    <div class="miniblock"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

То есть когда мы пишем `left:50%;` мы сдвигаем данный блок на 50% длины родительского блока слева, вдобавок `transform:translate(-50%);` - это будет значить что мы подвинем сам блок на 50% назад по своей длине.

Comment: Этот метод не кроссбраузерный, да и 6 там не поместится, сломается.